# Dynamics365 - retrieve Query/FetchXML on a Advanced find results page

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm

Is there a possibility to retrieve an advanced find query/fetchxml on a result page? Before I trigger Results button I am able to press Fetchxml button but on a results page not. Is there a possibiltiy to retrieve this query/xml via javascript or C# and it has to be on a results page.

Comment: Just curious - why?

Comment: @ArunVinoth client requirements ;)

Answer (score 0):

I am not 100% sure if we are talking about the same thing, but it is possible to state a query using Fetchxml.

Have a look at [this page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/use-fetchxml-construct-query). 
Here they use FetchExpression(string) to query with the regular organization service. You just need the organization service and the fetchxml to query it. Little example (from the link above!):

```
// Retrieve all accounts owned by the user with read access rights to the accounts 
   and   
// where the last name of the user is not Cannon.   
string fetch2 = @"  
<fetch mapping='logical'>  
  <entity name='account'>   
     <attribute name='accountid'/>   
     <attribute name='name'/>   
     <link-entity name='systemuser' to='owninguser'>   
        <filter type='and'>   
           <condition attribute='lastname' operator='ne' value='Cannon' />   
        </filter>   
     </link-entity>   
  </entity>   
</fetch> ";   

EntityCollection result = _serviceProxy.RetrieveMultiple(new 
FetchExpression(fetch2));
foreach (var c in result.Entities)
{
   System.Console.WriteLine(c.Attributes["name"]);
}
```

As you see this is most likely a console job. How you use the Entities itself then is up to you.

Comment: Sadly this fetchxml cannot be hardcoded, because everytime there could be a different one. As I said before, maybe I shoud clarify what I want to achieve: so if user makes some advanced search and gets redirected to the results page there should be a button that sends the result to an external system, my idea was: somehow get query expression pass it to plugin, for example via javascript and then from plugin fetch results again, because on a results page it gets paginated and then make an API call sending required data to external system.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, there are no hooks to customize the Advanced Find page, so there's no way to add JavaScript to do what you want.

However, you could write a plugin that fires on the `RetrieveMultiple` message.

In the plugin you can get the `QueryExpression` from the [RetrieveMultipleRequest](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamicscrm-2016/developers-guide/gg327661(v%3Dcrm.8)#properties)

`var q = (QueryExpression)context.InputParameters["Query"];`

Then [convert it](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/org-service/sample-convert-queries-fetch-queryexpression) to FetchXML.

```
var conversionRequest = new QueryExpressionToFetchXmlRequest
{
    Query = q
};
var conversionResponse = (QueryExpressionToFetchXmlResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(conversionRequest);
var fetchXml = conversionResponse.FetchXml;
```

Please note I have not tested the above code. And since I have not done this exact technique it's possible that you can cast the Query directly to FetchXML and skip the conversion call.

So, you might want to try this:
`var q = (FetchExpression)context.InputParameters["Query"];`

RetrieveMultiple plugins have their [caveats](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/guidance/server/limit-registration-plugins-retrieve-retrievemultiple). But, [how bad is it](https://salimadamoncrm.com/2016/12/29/plugin-on-retrieve-and-retrieve-multiple-how-bad-is-it/)?

On a related note, if the user saves the Advanced Find as a personal view, its FetchXML can be retrieved from the [UserQuery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/userquery-saved-view-entity) entity.

Comment: Actually it might be a good idea, but just maybe I should clarify what I want to achieve in a whole picture and maybe you could suggest something else. So if user makes some advanced search and gets redirected to the results page there should be a button that sends the result to an external system, my idea was: somehow get query expression pass it to plugin, for example via javascript and then from plugin fetch results again, because on a results page it gets paginated and then make an API call sending required data to external system.

Comment: I know of no way to add a button to Advanced Find, so I think you have to train the users to save the Advanced Find as a UserQuery, then you can have a plugin that fires onCreate of UserQuery to retrieve the UserQuery's FetchXML, run it, and export the results. You'll probably want to institute some sort of naming convention for users to distinguish views they want to automatically export from those they're using for other purposes.

Comment: Okay I see. But do you think there is another approach to this situation? Is there a possibility to fetch/retrieve results from grid via javascript? There is an option to pass SelectedControlAllItemIds or SelectedControlAllItemReferences from Ribbon on button click but it only passes paginated  result - for example 50 of 1000.